# How to check a text contains \

Tags: python

```
def check(text):
    pattern = re.compile(r'\\')
    rv = re.match(pattern, text)
    if rv:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print check('\mi') # True
print check('\ni') # False
```

Actually,I want text contains '\' is illegal.

But '\n', '\b',etc, python treats them specially,so I can not match them out.

Any solutions?

Comment: Try **"\\\\\"** as your pattern. I think you might have to escape it once for python, then escape _that_ again for the regex compiler.

Comment: First off, `re.match` match the string from beginning you can use `re.search` in order to search through the whole text, secondly you don't need regex for this simple task you can simply check teh membership with `in` operator.

Comment: If you have `'\ni'` in your source code the string contains no backslash. The string contains a newline followed by an `i`. Don't confuse the **representation** of a string with the content of the string.

Comment: If simply checking for a literal '\' is your goal, then a simple `in` operation might do (i.e. `"\\" in text`).

Comment: `\ni` **DOES NOT** contain backslash. It contains two characters, newline character and i letter. `\mi` on the other hand, contains backslash. Learn more about [string literals, escape characters, raw strings etc.](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals). [`pylint`](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint) static analysis tool may be helpful, as it yields `anomalous-backslash-in-string` error.

Comment: can you clarify if you want to detect ``\`` even in `'\ni'` ? one way is to pass raw string: `check(r'\ni')`

Comment: @spasic we focu on the check function,rather than the input text

Comment: @bin381 assuming python 2, try `return '\\' in text.encode('string-escape')` ... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428117/casting-raw-strings-python for details

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need or want to use a regex for this?

```
 return '\\' in text
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `r'\'` doesn't work like you'd expect.  See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30283082/why-does-the-single-backslash-raw-string-in-python-cause-a-syntax-error (though there is no good answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
def check(text):
    rv = re.search('(\\\\)|(\\\n)', string)
    if rv:
        return True
    else:
        return False
string = "\mi"
print check(string) 
string = "\ni"
print check(string)
```

Result:

> > > ================================ RESTART ===============
> > >
> > > ```
> > > True
> > > True
> > > ```

`\\\n` includes newlines.
You can specifically search this way for `\n` by escaping `\\` and adding `\n`. Works with `\b` etc...

Comment: string = "\ni" return False

Comment: Weird I tested this on 2 different machines (VDI) gives me True in both cases.