# Converting Byte to String and Back Properly in Python3?

Tags: python, type-conversion, byte

Given a random byte (i.e. not only numbers/characters!), I need to **convert it to a string** and then **back to the inital byte** without loosing information. This seems like a basic task, but I ran in to the following problems:

Assuming:

```
rnd_bytes = b'w\x12\x96\xb8'
len(rnd_bytes)
```

prints: `4`

Now, converting it to a string. Note: I need to set `backslashreplace` as it otherwise returns a 'UnicodeDecodeError' or would loose information setting it to another flag value.

```
my_str = rnd_bytes.decode('utf-8' , 'backslashreplace')
```

Now, I have the string. 
I want to convert it back to exactly the original byte (size 4!):

According to  python ressources and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3), there are different possibilities:

```
conv_bytes = bytes(my_str, 'utf-8')
conv_bytes = my_str.encode('utf-8')
```

But len(conv_bytes) returns `10`.

I tried to analyse the outcome:

```
>>> repr(rnd_bytes)
"b'w\\x12\\x96\\xb8'"
>>> repr(my_str)
"'w\\x12\\\\x96\\\\xb8'"
>>> repr(conv_bytes)
"b'w\\x12\\\\x96\\\\xb8'"
```

It would make sense to replace `'\\\\'`. `my_str.replace('\\\\','\\')` doesn't change anything. Probably, because four backslashes represent only two. So, `my_str.replace('\\','\')` would find the `'\\\\'`, but leads to

> SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

due to the last argument `'\'`. This had been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14453186/4673476), where the following suggestion came up:

```
>>> my_str2=my_str.encode('utf_8').decode('unicode_escape')
>>> repr(my_str2)
"'w\\x12\\x96¸'"
```

This replaces the `'\\\\'` but seems to add / change some other characters:

```
>>> conv_bytes2 = my_str2.encode('utf8')
>>> len(conv_bytes2)
6
>>> repr(conv_bytes2)
"b'w\\x12\\xc2\\x96\\xc2\\xb8'"
```

There *must* be a prober way to convert a (complex) byte to a string and back. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What purpose are you trying to achieve by turning arbitrary bytes into text?

Comment: I have a given function that needs a string as input and outputs the same string / sometimes edited string. But I receive the input string as byte and need to process it further as byte. This  would go beyond the scope of the discussion here but it's a basic task so that there has to be a possibility.

Comment: It's not a basic task, because not all bytes are text.

Comment: why don't you use hex? does the string have to be readable?

Comment: @legalalien It can be but it doesn't have to be. The string is only for the processing algorithm. Please feel free to write an answer if you know how to use hex to solve the conversion problem.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could try to convert it to hex format. Then it is easy to convert it back to byte format.

Sample code to convert bytes to string:

```
hex_str = rnd_bytes.hex()
```

Here is how 'hex_str' looks like:

```
'771296b8'
```

And code for converting it back to bytes:

```
new_rnd_bytes = bytes.fromhex(hex_str)
```

The result is:

```
b'w\x12\x96\xb8'
```

For processing you can use:

```
readable_str = ''.join(chr(int(hex_str[i:i+2], 16)) for i in range(0, len(hex_str), 2))
```

But never try to encode readable string, here is how readable string looks like:

```
'w\x12\x96¸'
```

After processing readable string convert it back to hex format before converting it back to bytes string like:

```
hex_str = ''.join([str(hex(ord(i)))[2:4] for i in readable_str])
```

Comment: Great solution! I was struggling with this for hours! Thanks!

Comment: It is funny, I struggled with the same thing, and came back to my answer to resolve it.

Answer (score 4):

> Now, converting it to a string. Note: I need to set backslashreplace as it otherwise returns a 'UnicodeDecodeError' or would loose information setting it to another flag value.

The UTF-8 encoding cannot interpret every possible sequence of bytes as a string. Using `backslashreplace` gives you a string that preserves the information for bytes that couldn't be converted:

```
>>> rnd_bytes = b'w\x12\x96\xb8'
>>> rnd_bytes.decode('utf-8', 'backslashreplace')
'w\x12\\x96\\xb8'
```

but that representation is not very useful for converting back.

Instead, use an encoding that **does** interpret every possible sequence of bytes as a string. The most straightforward of these is ISO-8859-1, which simply maps each byte one at a time to the first 256 Unicode code points respectively.

```
>>> rnd_bytes.decode('iso-8859-1')
'w\x12\x96¸'
>>> rnd_bytes.decode('iso-8859-1').encode('iso-8859-1') == rnd_bytes
True
```